# My .env file is invisible in VSCode, can't search for it, can't see it

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables

In VSCode I used to be able to see my `.env` file on the explorer view and search for it using 'go to file', I'm not sure what happened but now my .env is invisible, can't search for it, can't see it.

I have other files `.env.staging` `.env.production` these all show up just find, but for some reason .env is invisible

The only pluggin I'm currently using is Vim, but I disabled it and the issue remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your `settings.json`

[image]

find `"files.exclude"` and either comment out or remove `.env`

```js
"files.exclude": {
  "**/.classpath": true,
  "**/.factorypath": true,
  "**/.project": true,
  "**/.settings": true,
  "**/node_modules": true
  // "**/.env": true
},
```

Comment: THANKS, It was not in settings.json, but I dug through the menu settings and at first it wasn't showing up, but then I clicked, "modified in workspace" and .env was shown as being excluded, I removed the exclusion, then restarted a few times and it started showing up.

Answer (score 1):

As other answered, editing `file.exclude` could be one way of solving.

However, `"explorer.excludeGitIgnore": true` can also be the culprit since you might gitIgnore your .env files and have this on. This was the problem for me.